# Unable to reference Url.content inside my model view model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following model class inside my asp.net vmc web application :-

```
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string ImageOrDefault(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
        {
            var imagePath = uploadsDirectory + filename + ".png";
            var imageSrc = File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imagePath))
                               ? imagePath : defaultImage;

            return imageSrc;
        }

        private static string defaultImage = "/Content/uploads/virtual-data-center.png";
        private static string uploadsDirectory = Url.Contnet("/Content/uploads/");
    }
}
```

but i am unable to reference the `Url.content` in my last line of code, although i have included the `using System.Security.Policy;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an extension method UrlHelper class then:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    private static string defaultImage = "/Content/uploads/virtual-data-center.png";

    public static string ImageOrDefault(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string fileName)
    {
        var imagePath = urlHelper.Content("/Content/uploads/") + fileName + ".png";

        HttpContextBase httpContext = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        var imageSrc = File.Exists(httpContext.Server.MapPath(imagePath))
                           ? imagePath : defaultImage;

        return imageSrc;
    }
}
```

Also don't use `HttpContext.Current` if you don't have to. You can use it in your view like this:

```
@Url.ImageOrDefault("somefile")
```